# Happy: Order of Productions Removes R/R Conflicts

Tags: haskell, lr-grammar, happy, reduce-reduce-conflict

I have a grammar that, depending on the order of productions, happy reports 3 reduce/reduce conflicts or none. The minimal example I can find is:

```
%tokentype {Token}
%token
    int     { Int }
    '-'     { Neg }
    both    { Both }
%nonassoc both
%left '-'
%nonassoc NEG
%%
E : int                  {IntE}
  | both E E             {BothE $2 $3}
  | '-' E %prec NEG      {NegE $2}
  | E '-' E              {SubE $1 $3}
{
data Token = Int | Neg | Both deriving Show
data Expr = BothE Expr Expr | IntE | SubE Expr Expr | NegE Expr deriving Show
}
```

This has 3 reduce-reduce conflicts, based around the inability to distinguish "`both 7 -3`" and "`both 7-3 2`". Fair enough!

However, if you swap the last two productions for E (`'-' E %prec NEG` and `E '-' E`), the reduce/reduce conflicts disappear. More puzzling, if you then remove the `%prec NEG` directive, they return. I am quite confused as to what is happening here: why would the order matter?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me...

Comment: But a bug in Happy, or in my understanding of how %prec works?

Comment: I think Happy is at fault here.